# how to find k components in a directed graph using Girvan-Newman algorithm?

Tags: graph, components, graph-algorithm, digraphs

I am aware of [Girvan - Newman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girvan%E2%80%93Newman_algorithm) algorithm - here is the algorithm :

1. The [betweenness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) of all existing edges in the network is calculated first.
2. The edge with the highest betweenness is removed.
3. The betweenness of all edges affected by the removal is recalculated.
4. Steps 2 and 3 are repeated until no edges remain.

But I want to use this algorithm to find k components in a directed graph, where
k is a given integer.
How can I do this? is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Who said this doesn't work for a directed graph?

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is directed, you just need to process the directed version of the edgebetweenness, i.e. count the *directed* shortest paths going through an edge.

Regarding your parameter k, you must remove the most central links until you obtain k separated components. In other words, you don't need to apply step 4 until no edge remain: you can stop before, when you've reached the required k. The nodes contained in the resulting components correspond to your communities from the initial graph.